# What does script[/[^\d]+/, 0] do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Specifically: `script = script[/[^\d]+/, 0] if script`

My guess is it's some sort of substring function, but it's hard to find documentation on the Googles about it.

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-5B-5D

Comment: same as `script.sub(/[^\d]+/, 0)` I think

Answer (score 3):

It replaces `string` with the first sequence of non-digit characters in `script` if it is a string. It is a badly written code, and can be better written as

```
script &&= script[/\D+/]
```

Answer (score -1):

The brackets are equivalent to ruby's match. The stuff within "/ /" is a regular expression.

The ^ means not.
The \d is for digits
The + is for 1 or more

You would have to learn more about regular expressions, but i believe that it is saying replace the value of script (if it exists) with just the characters that arent digits.

Play around with http://rubular.com/ to get a better feel for it.